# sqoop incremental lastmodified with merge-key

Tags: sqoop

I am trying to import the updated records in HDFS. Earlier I had three part file in HDFS.When I run below tool it gave an error that merge key is required.

`sqoop import --table employee --username training --password training --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/loudacre --incremental lastmodified --check-column modified --last-value '2016-08-22 19:02:41'`

However, when I used the **merge-key** option I can see only part file with all the records in it.

Answer (score 6):

Though a very old post, I'm adding points for those with same question.

@Deepak_Spark_Beginner : If error says 'merge key is required' then it means that the "--target-dir" is already present. since you did not specify this in Sqoop command, the default value i.e. table name 'employee' is picked. Meaning, a directory by name employee is already present.

Next, when you specify a merge key during incremental approach below sequence of action happens,

1. All rows which satisfy the last value criteria are imported to a temporary location. This execution runs map only jobs. This can be seen in logs as follows

8/10/30 13:27:52 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%

18/10/30 13:27:58 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 67% reduce 0%

18/10/30 13:27:59 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% **reduce 0%**

2. Next, merge action takes place between your original target directory 'employee' and the temporary target directory, wherein the column specified in --merge-key is used to update the existing data. This runs mappers and reducer which can be seen in logs as follows

18/10/30 13:28:08 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%

18/10/30 13:28:14 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 17% reduce 0%

18/10/30 13:28:16 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%

18/10/30 13:28:20 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% **reduce 100%**

reducer job is required because of obvious reasons that key matching has to scan complete dataset. Plus you can verify the same by your file name which would have a 'r' denoting reducer output.

This is the reason why you see only 1 file in your output.

you commented "I mean just to get the modifed field from database and update HDFS using lastmodified". Well, this is what had happened. If you check the output, the execution has got modified fields from database and updated in HDFS. Only difference is that output is merged into one single file.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected I guess. Generally, **merge tool** is run after an incremental import with the `--incremental lastmodified` mode.

When merging the datasets, it is assumed that there is a unique primary key value in each record (*mentioned as `--merge-key`*).

The merge tool will run mapreduce job to merge all datasets into one, taking the newest available rows for each `--merge-key`.

Check sqoop [docs](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_syntax_8) for more details.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this.I mean just to get the modifed field from database and update HDFS using lastmodified.